# React Native Expo / FCM: you attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling "firebase.app()"

Tags: typescript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo, react-native-firebase

I have a React Native/Expo app wherein I am trying to use Firebase Cloud Messaging on an Android Device. My web instance of this works just fine, but I am stuck on implementing a successful Firebase Cloud Messaging initialization on Android.

I am building the app with `expo build:android` and downloading it onto my phone, so that I may test the Google Login in conjunction with a few other API calls that happen.

I am completely stuck on this React Native Firebase error: `you attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling "firebase.app()"`

**firebase.tsx**

```
import { Platform, Alert } from "react-native";

// ANDROID
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
// Android uses the google-services.json file for config

// WEB
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, onMessage, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { 
    FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    FIREBASE_WEB_VAPID_KEY,
    // @ts-ignore
} from '@env';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const init = async () => {
    switch(Platform.OS) {
      // ANDROID INIT
      case 'android': 
        const alreadyAuthed = await messaging().hasPermission();
        const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
        const enabled =
          (authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
          authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL ||
          alreadyAuthed);

        if (enabled) {
          const token = await messaging().getToken();

          messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
          });

          messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
          });

          if (token) {
            return token;
          }
        }
        return null;

      // WEB INIT
      case 'web': 
        let web_messaging;
        let web_app;

      
        if (!web_app) {
          web_app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }

        web_messaging = await getMessaging(web_app);
        console.log(messaging);

        onMessage(web_messaging, (payload) => {
          console.log('Message received')
          console.log(payload)
        })

        if (web_messaging) {
          try {
            const token = await getToken(web_messaging, { vapidKey: FIREBASE_WEB_VAPID_KEY })
            console.log(token);
            if (token) {
              return token;
            }
          } catch(err) {
            // TODO err handling
            console.log(err)
          }
        }
        return null;

      // TODO
      case 'ios':
        break;
    }
};

const FIREBASE = {
    init,
};

export default FIREBASE;
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "frontend-2",
    "slug": "frontend-2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./firebase-google.json",
      "package": "com.michaelsolomon.frontend2",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "certificateHash": "--redacted--"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./src/assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin"
    ]
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseApp;
```

Does `expo build:android` re-build the `/android` file and export it to Expo? I have made numerous changes the coincide with various guides about this particular error. How can I use `expo build:android` and source it from my Bare Workflow/Ejected `/android` file?

Can I use the same package for Android and Web? I was having a lot of trouble making the same `firebase/app` and `/messaging` package work for Android, so I've been trying to follow [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage). I have not seen a working solution for this/my issue, yet. I was not able to call `getToken`, and thus, save the device token in my backend on Android. Should I just use `expo-notifications`?

Comment: Please did you solved this, The same issue here